# HTML table from PHP an array

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I have 2 arrays, one has

```
$heading = array(Heading1, Heading2,...Heading10);
```

and second has

```
$value = array($y1,$y2,$y3,...$y10);
```

And each `$y1`, `$y2` ... `$y10` has numerous digits in each, like

```
$y1=(digit1,digit2,digit3...);
$y2=(digit1,digit2,digit3...);
$y3=(digit1,digit2,digit3...);

.
.
$y10=(numerous digits);
```

The number of digits will be the same in all `$y1` ... `$y10`.

I want to print these array into an HTML table in PHP, where `Heading1` correspond to `$y1`, and `Heading2` correspond to `$y2` and so on), like this:

```
Heading1     Heading2       Heading 3         Heading1o
digit1       digit1          digit1
digit2                        
digit3          
digit4
digit5       so on           so on            so on
digit6
digit7
digit8
digit9
digit10     digit10         digit10           digit10
.             .                .                 .
.             .                .                 .
```

Can Anyone please help me?

Comment: It sounds like you need a PHP developer.  I'm not sure what you would like us to do?  Write the code for you?

Comment: @sg-  I am trying to print these arrays into an HTML table but I am not getting the expected result, Can you please suggest me or tell me the logic, I am a beginner.that will be very helpful for me.

Comment: have you tried anything? try to write your own code and ask here if there is an error

Comment: Please post what you tried so far? It will make us believe that you did some effort at your end first and then you asked to us.You will get answers then

Comment: here i was trying to print the all values without heading. but i was getting scattered table .                                                                                   echo "<table>";
foreach($data as $key=>$value)
{
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>$key</td>";
     for($x=0; $x<count($value); $x++) 
     {
          if (is_numeric($value[$x])) 
     {
        echo "<td>".sprintf('%02d', $value[$x])."</td>";
     }
     else
     {
         echo "<td>". $value[$x]."</td>";
     }
     }
     echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$heading = array('Heading1','Heading2','Heading10');    

$y1=array('y1','y1','y1');
$y2=array('y2','y2','y2');
$y3=array('y3','y3','y3');  
$value = array($y1,$y2,$y3);
$heading1='<table><tr>';
$td='<tr>'; 
for($i=0;$i<(count($heading));$i++){
    $heading1.='<th>'.$heading[$i].'';
foreach($value[$i] as $values){
        $td.='<td>'.$values.'</td>';
    }
    $td.='</tr></tr>';
}
$table=$heading1.$td.'</table>';
echo $table;
?>
```

This will work

Comment: @suraj try to build some logic, try to learn your own code than depending others like this..don't post silly questions like this again before trying yourself  for a day or two..

Comment: I spent 2 days ,I was getting some unexpected result.I am not asking for whole code.I am lacking in some logic,It will be very helpful for me ,if anyone can correct me.

Comment: check the code ..it works..made some changes in the code

Comment: Okay sir, I am making changes according to my requirement.Thank You so much.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code,

```
$heading = array('Heading1','Heading2','Heading10');    

$y1=array('y1','y1','y1');
$y2=array('y2','y2','y2');
$y3=array('y3','y3','y3');  
$values = array($y1,$y2,$y3);
$table='<table><tr>';
for($i=0;$i<(count($heading));$i++){
    $table.='<th>'.$heading[$i].'</th>';
}
$table.= </tr>
foreach($values as $value){
    $table.='<tr>';
    foreach($value as $row){
      $table.='<td>'.$values.'</td>';
    }    
    $table.='</tr>';
}

$table.='</table>';
echo $table;
```

thanks.

Comment: Thanks sir for try.i tried with previous answered , but thank you so much for writing code.